# Аргумент командной строки n

Tags: java

Как передать число `n` в виде аргумента командной строки?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int result[] = ArrayOfPrimeNumbers(30);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Factor: " + result[i]);
    }
}
public static int[] ArrayOfPrimeNumbers(int n) {
    int countPrimeNumbers = 0;
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        if (isPrime(i)) {
            countPrimeNumbers++;
        }
    }
    int newArrayofPrime[] = new int[countPrimeNumbers];
    int count = 0;
    while (count < countPrimeNumbers) {
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
            if (isPrime(i)) {
                newArrayofPrime[count] = i;
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return newArrayofPrime;
}
public static boolean isPrime(int n) {
    if (n <= 1)
        return false;

    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
        if (n % i == 0)
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int n = args[0];
    int result[] = ArrayOfPrimeNumbers(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Factor: " + result[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: @Саша, примите ответ по возможности, чтобы вопрос не висел открытым :)